# Trigger a mouseover on markers by hovering on address

Tags: google-maps

I am trying to call mouseover event on markers when a user hovers over address, but that doesn't seem to work. Open this page

http://tinyurl.com/bp94qdy

type subway and click go. This is link in the address

```
 <a  onmouseover="javascript:google.maps.event.trigger(markersArray['+i+'],onmouseover);"
```

I am also trying to zoom the map on initializing so that all markers fit in it, but that gives me an undefined GLatLngBounds error. The code used is
     function calculateCenter() {

```
  /* var latlngbounds = new GLatLngBounds();
  for (var i = 0; i < latlng.length; i++)
   {
       latlngbounds.extend(latlng[i]);
    }
    map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter(), map.getBoundsZoomLevel(latlngbounds));*/
    center = map.getCenter();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the syntax for [**google.maps.event.trigger**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#event)
This will not work:

```
<a onmouseover="javascript:google.maps.event.trigger(markersArray['+i+'],onmouseover);" ...
```

because the event name should be a string, so:

```
<a  onmouseover="javascript:google.maps.event.trigger(markersArray['+i+'],'onmouseover');" ...
```

or even better, use DHTML:

```
var div = document.createElement('DIV');
div.onmouseover = function(i){
google.maps.event.trigger(markersArray[i],'mouseover');
}
div.innerHTML = contentString;
var listContainer = document.getElementById("listingAddress");
listContainer.appendChild(div);
```

with quotation marks around the event name.
and there is another error:
 `var markerBounds = new GLatLngBounds();`
is API V2 syntax. In the V3 API it is

```
var markerBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
```

Comment: Its actually inside single quotes so adding double or single quotes for the event gives a syntax error.    listing +='<a  onmouseover="javascript:google.maps.event.trigger(markersArray['+i+'],onmouseover);" style="width:100px;height: 20px;" class="sty-hyperlink" target="_blank" href="https://maps.google.com/maps?daddr='+address_link+'">';

Comment: It's not inside single quotes. (I am looking at the page on the link you posted). Perhaps you have a different version on your local machine?

Comment: I mean the whole line is, if you look at the source in firefox look at line 284

Comment: Thanks a lot, now i tried to put the event name in quotes, but still doesn't trigger. I have removed the other code for the moment while fixing this one.

Comment: Ahh, but the Marker object does not have an event called 'onmouseover'. Instead it has 'mouseover'. Sorry I overlooked that. :-)

Comment: Thank you so much, worked like a charm :) . I am now trying to fix the zoom level to show all markers.